# How do I change font in array environment inside an equation?

Tags: equations, amsmath, fontsize, arrays

I have the following code to define a piece-wise equation as shown in the following figure:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{xput_vc}
Throughput_{VC} = 
\begin{array}{cc}
  1 & N_{VC} \leq N_{slave} \\
  \frac{N_{req2slave}\times N_{VC}}{N_{req2slave}+Latency} &  N_{VC} > N_{slave} \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}
```

[image: piecewise equation]

I want to decrease the font size of the conditions in that equation (NVC less then NSlave) but I can't seem to be able to get it to do that. I tried typing `\footnotesize` before the condition but it makes no difference.

How can I change the font size inside the array nested in an equation environment?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. If you really need (explanatory) text in an equation use `\text{Throughput}` or `\intertext`. And you need `amsmath` as package, but you can't change the font size (this way) in math mode, in addition there's a `case` command that's meant for such piecewise functions/definitions etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are ways to do it, with the `cases` environment. In the second way, you can have the `1` centred easily with `\hfill` (thanks to @Mico's suggestion):

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
      \label{xput_vc}
      \text{Throughput}_{VC} =
      \begin{cases}
        1 & \scriptstyle N_{VC} \leq N_\text{slave} \\
        \frac{N_\text{req2slave}\times N_{VC}}{N_\text{req2slave}+\text{Latency}} & \scriptstyle N_{VC} > N_\text{slave} \\
      \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
    \vskip1cm
    \begin{equation}
      \label{xput_vc}
      \text{Throughput}_{VC} =
      \begin{cases}
        \hfill 1\hfill & \scriptstyle N_{VC} \leq N_\text{slave} \\
        \frac{N_\text{req2slave}\times N_{VC}}{N_\text{req2slave}+\text{Latency}} & \scriptstyle N_{VC} > N_\text{slave} \\
      \end{cases}
    \end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How do I center the "1" in this environment?

Comment: You can with the small `makebox` package. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Mico: I didn't even think of using it, not knowing how TeX measures the boxes that play here. I've incorporated it in my answer. Thanks for you suggestion: the code is much neater!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
\text{\footnotesize $N_{VC} \leq N_{slave}$}
```

Comment: Maybe, but you certainly shouldn't!

Comment: I agree, this seems too hacky; what _should_ I do though?

Comment: I must say, this did actually work fine though -- upvote for that